# ng-grid totalServerItems issue

Tags: ng-grid

I am using ng-grid to display my returned JSON data

**restApp.js**

```
function request(method, url, data, params){
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var fullpath = _server+url;

    if(typeof(data) == 'string'){
        params = data;
        data = null;

        fullpath = fullpath+params;
    }
    //alert(fullpath);

    $http({
        method: method,
        url: fullpath,
        data: data
    }).success(function(data){
    console.log(data);
        deferred.resolve(data);
    }).error(function(err){
        deferred.reject(err);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}


var getAlertsWithOptions = function(pageNum, per_page, search, sort, public_alert){
    /*Returns all alerts, with the option of specifying 
    pagination, searching and sorting. In case pagination 
    is requested, both parameters ‘page’ and ‘per_page’ can 
    be supplied to customize the pagination. Default value 
    for ‘per_page’ if not supplied will be 10, default for 
    ‘page’ is 1. Sorting is also possible by supplying a 
    ‘sort’ request parameter with any combination of the 
    values ‘priority’, ‘state’, ‘createdAt’, ‘summary’, 
    ‘active’,’details’. Using ‘-‘ in front of the sort 
    field will sort in descending order. Default sort field 
    if no sorting supplied will be ‘-createdAt’. Filtering 
    is provided via the ‘q’ request parameter. This will 
    filter alerts by their ‘summary’ or ‘details’ fields.
    Filtering is case-insensitive*/
    var url = 'alert';
    var params = '';
    //alert(totalServerItems);
    var options = [];
    //alert(pageNum+"--"+per_page+"--"+search+"--"+sort+"--"+public_alert);
        if(typeof(pageNum) != 'undefined'){                
            options.push('page=' + pageNum);
        }
        if(typeof(per_page) != 'undefined'){                
            options.push('per_page=' + per_page);
        }
        if(typeof(search) != 'undefined' || search != null){                
            options.push('q=' + search);
        }
        if(typeof (sort) != 'undefined'){              
            options.push('sort=' + sort);
        }
        if(typeof (public_alert) != 'undefined'){              
            options.push('public=' + public_alert);
        }

        if (options.length > 0) {
            params = '?';
            params = params + options.join('&');                
        }

    return request('GET',url,params);
}
```

**adminAlertCtrl.js**

```
var adminAlertCtrl = angular.module('siApp').controller('adminAlertController',['$scope','restApp', '$modal', 'selectedAlert', 'loadAlerts',
function($scope, restApp, $modal, selectedAlert, loadAlerts){

$scope.displayAlert = false;
$scope.close = function(){$scope.displayAlert = false}
var _currentSort = '';

$scope.sortOptions = [
    {name:"Date", value:"-createdAt"},
    {name:"Priority", value:"priority"},
    {name:"Status", value:"state"},
    {name:"Name",value:"summary"},
    {name:"Details",value:"details"},
    {name:"Privacy", value:"publicAlert"}];

var initLoad = true;
$scope.$watch('sortModel', function(newVal){
    _currentSort = newVal;
    if(initLoad) {
        initLoad = false;
        return;
    }

    //the 1 represents the page starting on. Every time a new sort is specified, we take the user back to the first page of this newly sorted data
    restApp.getAlertsWithOptions(1, $scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.searchFilter, [_currentSort.value]).then(function(data){
        if (data !== 'No alerts found') {
            //add dateObj to filter
            data.map(function(_alert){
                return _alert.dateObj = new Date(_alert.createdAt).toDateString();
            });
            $scope.myData = data;
        } else {
            $scope.myData = [];
        }
    },function(err){
        alert('Error refreshing alerts: '+ err);
    });
 });


//add dateObj to filter
if(loadAlerts != "No alerts found") {
    loadAlerts.map(function(_alert){
        return _alert.dateObj = new Date(_alert.createdAt).toDateString();
    });
    $scope.myData = loadAlerts;
 }else{
    $scope.displayAlert = true;
    $scope.pageAlert= {type: "warning", message:"No Alerts Found"}
    $scope.myData = [];
 }
$scope.totalServerItems = 0;
 //ngGrid
 $scope.pagingOptions = {
    pageSizes: [5,10,20],
    pageSize: 10,
    currentPage: 1,
    input:'text',
    totalServerItems: 'totalServerItems'
 };

 $scope.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [
        {field:"summary", displayName:"Name", sortable:false, cellTemplate: "<div><a ng-click='editAlert(row.entity)'>{{row.entity[col.field]}}</a></div>" },
        {field:"dateObj", displayName:"Date", sortable:false, cellTemplate: "<div>{{row.entity[col.field]}} </div>    "},
        {field:"priority",width:"90px" ,sortable:false, displayName:"Priority", cellTemplate:"<div ng-class='{high: row.getProperty(col.field) === \"HIGH\", med: row.getProperty(col.field) === \"MEDIUM\",  low: row.getProperty(col.field) === \"LOW\" }'>{{row.entity[col.field]}}</div>"},
        {field:"details", displayName: "Details", sortable:false},
        {field:"state", displayName:"Status", sortable:false}
     ],
    enablePaging: true,
    showFooter: true,
    pagingOptions: $scope.pagingOptions,
    multiSelect: false,

    data: 'myData'
 };

    function getPagedDataSet(pageSize, pageNum){
        console.log('page data set');
        console.log(pageSize);
        console.log(pageNum);


        restApp.getAlertsWithOptions(pageNum, pageSize, $scope.searchFilter, [_currentSort.value]).then(function(data){
            console.log('retireved data back for new page');

            //update the new page on the grid
            data.map(function(_alert){
                return _alert.dateObj = new Date(_alert.createdAt).toDateString();
            });
            $scope.totalServerItems = data.length;
            $scope.myData = data;
            alert($scope.totalServerItems);
        },function(err){
            console.log(err);
        })

    }

    $scope.$watch('pagingOptions', function (newVal, oldVal) {

      if (newVal !== oldVal && newVal.currentPage !== oldVal.currentPage) {
            getPagedDataSet($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage);
      }
    }, true);


  function reload(){
   restApp.getAlertsWithOptions(1, $scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.searchFilter, [_currentSort.value]).then(function(data){
       if (data !== 'No alerts found') {
           //add dateObj to filter
           data.map(function(_alert){
               return _alert.dateObj = new Date(_alert.createdAt).toDateString();
           });
           $scope.myData = data;
       } else {
           $scope.myData = [];
       }
   },function(err){
       alert('Error refreshing alerts: '+ err);
   });
 }

 $scope.searchFilter = '';
 $scope.filter = function(){
   restApp.getAlertsWithOptions(1, $scope.pagingOptions.pageSize,     $scope.searchFilter, ['-createdAt']).then(function(data){
     //add dateObj to filter          
       if (data !== 'No alerts found') {
           data.map(function(_alert){
               return _alert.dateObj = new Date(_alert.createdAt).toDateString();
           });
           $scope.myData = data;
       } else {
           $scope.myData = [];
       }

   },function(err){
       alert('Error searching alerts: '+ err);
   });
 }

 $scope.refresh = function(){
   $scope.displayAlert = false;
   reload();
 }

 $scope.editAlert = function(selAlert){
  //pass alert to selectedAlert

   selAlert = selAlert || {
        "publicAlert" : "1",
        "source" : "S",
        "priority" : "MEDIUM",
        "state" : "NEW"
   };

   selectedAlert.setAlert(selAlert);


   var modalInstance = $modal.open({
       templateUrl: 'views/alertModal.html',
       controller: "alertModalCtrl",
       backdrop: 'static',
       resolve:{
           states: alertCtrl.aStates,
           priorities: alertCtrl.aPriorities
       }
   });

   modalInstance.result.then(function(result){

       var msg = 'Alert Successfully ';
       if (result === 'create') {
           msg += 'Created';
       } else {
           msg += 'Updated';
       }
       reload();
       $scope.pageAlert = {
           "type": 'success',
           "message": msg
       }
       $scope.displayAlert = true;
   },function(){
       console.log('modal canceled');
   })

}
}]);

adminAlertCtrl.loadData = function($q, restApp){
var deferred = $q.defer();

restApp.getAlertsWithOptions(1, 10, undefined, ['-createdAt']).then(function(data){
    deferred.resolve(data);
},function(err){
    deferred.reject(err);
});

return deferred.promise;
}

adminAlertCtrl.aStates = function($q, restApp){
  var deferred = $q.defer();

restApp.getAlertState().then(function(states){
    deferred.resolve(states);
},function(err){
    deferred.reject(err);
});

return deferred.promise;
}

adminAlertCtrl.aPriorities = function($q, restApp){
var deferred = $q.defer();

restApp.getAlertPriority().then(function(priorities){
    deferred.resolve(priorities);
},function(err){
    deferred.reject(err);
});

return deferred.promise;
}
```

[image]

[image]

So, my problem here is I am unable to get the count of **totalServerItems** so the pagination is not working properly.

My grid has total 13 items and the total items are counting page wise, in the first page it is showing the total items as 10 and in the second page total otems are showing as 3.

If I can get the total items count the paginations etc all functionality are working fine.
Kindly check my code and help me where I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You are having this problem because you receive data from the server only about a current page.
To make it work correctly you should send from server an **object** with total count of rows for this search and current page result:

```
{
    totalServerItems: 13,
    pagedData: Array(10)
}
```

And remove `totalServerItems:` property from `$scope.pagingOptions` coz it is part of `$scope.gridOptions`

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [ ... ],
    enablePaging: true,
    showFooter: true,
    pagingOptions: $scope.pagingOptions,
    multiSelect: false,

    data: 'myData',
    totalServerItems: 'totalServerItems' //like that
};
```